# Possible bug - Share a link to this question via email, , , or

Tags: bug

So, I just posted a question on Sharepoint SE, but as I went down the page, I took note of a text:

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email,
>   , , or .

[image: Here]

Is this normal? What were supposed to be there after "email"?

Comment: Do you have an ad-blocker installed? It looks like you might and that it may be blocking social media links.

Comment: @JamesFlattery In Fact I do! I'll try it later without it.

Comment: So what's the verdict?

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

[image]

Do you have a Twitter, Google+ or Facebook account?

Comment: Then it's a bug. Is it normal on your machine? On Chrome?